# GRPC Java Server Service

Tags: server, rpc, grpc-java

How can I trigger server side streaming service when any action service is called 
 by the client? Right now the streaming server can only send the response when it is called by the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem today. When the user subscribes to a stream, save the subscription request and stream observer in an array list/ normal list. Later when any action service is called. Create a new instance of the Stream service (which extends ServerStreamServiceGrpc.ServerStreamServiceImplBase) and call the required stream service from this new instance with the parameters from the array list. You don't need to use the same service instance which was used to create the server. When the user unsubscribes from the stream, just remove that subscription from the array list also. Make sure that onCompleted() is not called whenever you send any data from streaming service as it'll terminate the subscription. Here streaming refers to server side streaming.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. gRPC is request/response type protocol. Client has to call the relevant streaming RPC for server to stream.

Comment: It is possible. We had made GRPC server using Golang and implemented the same. (i.e. trigger server side streaming service when any action service is called). Idon't know how to do in Java.  Consider an example where server wants to constantly stream information to existing players in room 
about players who've joined room/server.